# Tracking Attendance at Events

Tags: windows, offline

I'm looking for some vendor software to track attendees by scanning their ID badges at different events.

Features I'm looking for:

- RFID compatability - Most readers are essentially USB keyboards, so this shouldn't be a problem.
- Reporting Functionality - We want to be able to load information about the attendee prior and export that information into a summary report after an event. We have the mapping between their ID card and their personal data.
- Able to scan their badge offline.
- Customize fields for describing the events.

My initial research returned mostly software used at trade conventions, where they print a badge and can scan a badge for check-in. There is no functionality to import data about the user from a different system.

Any help or leads is greatly appreciated. I would prefer an one-time license vs. a monthly fee. I like the idea of doing it through a web application but I can't justify the ongoing cost.